# Returning iterator over copied values from trait function

Tags: templates, rust, iterator, traits, lifetime

I require for a trait to have a function that returns an iterator over some value-type. A struct implementing this trait may simply store a (read-only) collection of values we want to iterate over.

I attempted a contrived example below:

```
use std::iter::Copied;
use std::collections::{hash_set, HashSet};

trait MyTrait<I: IntoIterator<Item = usize>> {
    fn iter(&self) -> I;
}

struct MyStruct{
    set: HashSet<usize>,
}

type Iter<'a> = Copied<hash_set::Iter<'a, usize>>;

impl MyTrait<Iter<'_>> for MyStruct {
    fn iter(&self) -> Iter<'_> {
        self.set.iter().copied()
    }
}
```

However, the above code yields the following compiler errors:

```
error: `impl` item signature doesn't match `trait` item signature
  --> src/lib.rs:15:5
   |
5  |     fn iter(&self) -> I;
   |     -------------------- expected `fn(&MyStruct) -> Copied<std::collections::hash_set::Iter<'_, usize>>`
...
15 |     fn iter(&self) -> Iter<'_> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ found `fn(&MyStruct) -> Copied<std::collections::hash_set::Iter<'_, usize>>`
   |
   = note: expected `fn(&MyStruct) -> Copied<std::collections::hash_set::Iter<'_, _>>`
              found `fn(&MyStruct) -> Copied<std::collections::hash_set::Iter<'_, _>>`
help: the lifetime requirements from the `impl` do not correspond to the requirements in the `trait`
  --> src/lib.rs:5:23
   |
5  |     fn iter(&self) -> I;
   |                       ^ consider borrowing this type parameter in the trait
```

The "expected" and "found" appear identical, so maybe this is an issue with anonymous lifetimes? How can I get this to work?

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=71f266537a6874d8ec769b591b705c01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler can't infer the correct lifetimes here, so you need to tell it what they are, like this:

```
impl<'a> MyTrait<Iter<'a>> for MyStruct {
    fn iter(&'a self) -> Iter<'a> {
        self.set.iter().copied()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't do that, because the trait doesn't have a lifetime requirement on `self` so neither can an implementor. To allow this, you can simply change the trait to this:

```
trait MyTrait<'a, I: 'a + IntoIterator<Item = usize>> {
    fn iter(&'a self) -> I;
}
```

Here `I: 'a + ...` is telling the compiler that no reference inside `I` may outlive `'a`, i.e. `self`.

Now you can implement `MyTrait` like this:

```
impl<'a> MyTrait<'a, Iter<'a>> for MyStruct {
    fn iter(&'a self) -> Iter<'a> {
        self.set.iter().copied()
    }
}
```

And for a type where the lifetimes really don't matter, because the `I` doesn't actually hold any references, you can still use lifetime elision:

```
impl MyTrait<'_, std::vec::IntoIter<usize>> for Vec<usize> {
    fn iter(&self) -> std::vec::IntoIter<usize> {
        self.clone().into_iter()
    }
}
```